# SQLAlchemy Transactions in Snowflake Seemingly Autocommitting despite explicitly setting Autocmmit to False

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, transactions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to wrap my SQL code in a transaction so that if it fails part way through then no partial changes will have been committed and instead will be rolled back to how the DB was before the transaction began.
I'm using sqlalchemy version 1.4.4 to execute SQL statements on a SnowFlake DB via python script.
I've tried a number of things and none worked. The change seems to have occurred when I check the SnowFlake console despite my not committing and instead rolling back.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding transactions.

**Expected result:**
I drop MY_TABLE inside of a transaction but it never gets committed and instead gets rolled back.  Now I should see my table still existing in DB.  I tried all 3 of the below code snippets.  I expected each one to do the same thing (not drop MY_TABLE).  Instead MY_TABLE doesn't exist when I check the DB (Snowflake console).

I'm starting to think I just don't understand transactions.  Please explain to me why a transaction would not do what I expected if that's the case.

**What I tried**

First I make sure to create MY_TABLE before each of these 3 attempts.

1. Attempt number one.  I thought create_engine().begin() would implicitly commit or rollback if transaction had a failure within it.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

with create_engine(connection_str).begin() as cnxn:
           cnxn.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MY_TABLE")
           raise Exception('Fail here')
```

2. Trying to explicitly rollback

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

with create_engine(connection_str, future=True).connect().execution_options(autocommit=False) as cnxn:
            try:
                cnxn.begin()
                cnxn.execute(text("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MY_TABLE"))
                raise Exception('Fail here')
                cnxn.commit()
            except:
                cnxn.rollback()
```

3. Trying to explicitly rollback and set autocommit in a different way.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

with create_engine(connection_str, future=True).connect() as cnxn:
            try:
                cnxn.autocommit = False
                cnxn.begin()
                cnxn.execute(text("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MY_TABLE"))
                raise Exception('Fail here')
                cnxn.commit()
            except:
                cnxn.rollback()
```

Comment: not sure how relevant this is, but as per https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions#label-transactions-ddl *Because a DDL statement is its own transaction, you cannot roll back a DDL statement; the transaction containing the DDL completes before you can execute an explicit ROLLBACK.*

Comment: @python_user  Thank you.  That's definitely it.  If you want to put this in an answer I'll accept it as the correct answer.